# Вывод в файл

Tags: c

Здравствуйте. 
Цель: нужно действительное число перевести в строку и записать в файл.
Вот что я написал:

```
 int main (){

    FILE *fp;
    int n = 10;

    char *buf;
    fp = fopen("D:\\some_file.txt", "wb");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        perror("ошибка открытия some_file.txt");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

       double Number = 1.2;
       char *tmp;
       sprintf(tmp, "%f", Number);
       fwrite(tmp, 20, strlen(tmp), fp);

    return 0;
```

}

И вроде бы все верно... но как только консолька запускается - виндовс пытается прекратить роботу приложения. В чем может состоять проблема?

p.s. `_codepad.org` выдает сообщение "Disallowed system call: SYS_dup"; компилю все это в codeblocks, компилятор gnu\gcc

Comment: Указатель tmp не инициализирован. Или делайте статический массив, или выделяйте память явно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как сказано выше, вы создали просто указатель на char и не инициализировали его.
А после пытались по адресу указателя записать данные, и поэтому падает программа, так как вы пытались обратится к памяти которую вам ни кто не давал.

измените

```
   char *tmp;
   sprintf(tmp, "%f", Number);
   fwrite(tmp, 20, strlen(tmp), fp);

на

   char tmp[20];
   sprintf(tmp, "%f", Number);
   fwrite(tmp, sizeof(char), strlen(tmp), fp);

или

   char *tmp = malloc(szeof(char) * 20);
   sprintf(tmp, "%f", Number);
   fwrite(tmp, sizeof(char), strlen(tmp), fp);
   free(tmp);
```